# Iterating through a nested list in dynamic block in terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to be able to create `vault` policies from a `yaml` configuration as follows

```yaml
policies:
  policy-test-1:
    - capabilities:
        - read
        - create
      path: /foo/lala
    - capabilities:
        - create
        - patch
      path: /voo/lala
  policy-test-2:
    - capabilities:
        - update
        - delete
      path: /foo/lala
```

i.e. I want to provision so that each policy document may be able to have multiple statements.

`var.policy_statements` is the output of `yamldecode` of the above file.

The following approach using `dynamic` blocks however fails

```
data "vault_policy_document" "this" {

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.policy_statements

    content {
      path = rule.value.path
      capabilities = rule.value.capabilities
    }
  }



}

resource "vault_policy" "this" {
  for_each = var.policy_statements

  name   = each.key
  policy = data.vault_policy_document.this[each.key].hcl

}
```

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../path/to/policies/main.tf  line 8, in data "vault_policy_document" "this":
│    8:       capabilities = rule.value.capabilities
│     ├────────────────
│     │ rule.value is list of object with 2 elements
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "capabilities" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../path/to/policies/main.tf line 8, in data "vault_policy_document" "this":
│    8:       capabilities = rule.value.capabilities
│     ├────────────────
│     │ rule.value is list of object with 1 element
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "capabilities" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
```

What is the correct way to run the loop, given that each object with the policy name (e.g. `policy-test-1`) is an array of objects having as keys `paths` and `capabilities`?

**UPDATE**: I have tried the following approach

```
locals {
  policies = flatten([
    for k, v in var.policy_statements : [
      for i, j in v : {
        capabilities = j.capabilities
        path = j.path
        name = k
      }
    ]
  ])
}

data "vault_policy_document" "this" {

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = local.policies

    content {
      path = rule.path
      capabilities = rule.capabilities
    }
  }



}

resource "vault_policy" "this" {
  for_each = local.policies

  name   = each.value.name
  policy = data.vault_policy_document.this[each.key].hcl

}
```

The error now is

```
 20:       capabilities = rule.capabilities
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "capabilities".
```

(same with `path`)

Why doesn't the `local.policies` haven't `path`/`capabilities` attributes, given that I am explicitly creating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the local.policies haven't path/capabilities attributes, given that I am explicitly creating them

Because your first element in the yaml file is `policies`. So you have to start iterating from that (added `.policies`):

```
locals {
  policies = flatten([
    for k, v in var.policy_statements.policies : [
      for i, j in v : {
        capabilities = j.capabilities
        path = j.path
        name = k
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```